# GAE Datastore Administration - webpage is not available

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-administration, administration

I was looking to check out the experimental [backup/restore feature](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) of the app-engine datastore, so I followed the instructions and enabled "Datastore Administration" as explained in the link.

After doing so, instead of seeing the Datastore administration controls in the dashboard I am getting a ["This webpage is not available"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtqJJ.png) on chrome and ["Server not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwaUk.png) on Firefox.

I understand this is experimental but still any help from the app-engine team would be appreciated in terms of what's going on with this feature :)

**UPDATE**: I tried this on another app (with an empty datastore) and the Datastore Administration page comes up normally.

Comment: Why not login using: https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: @voscausa I am not sure I understand

Comment: Dou you stll have the same problem? I could not which url you used to access the datastore admin, and I suggested to use the default one.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean byt that - as far as I know I am using the default url - appengine.google.com/datastore/admin?&app_id=s~appname&version_id=appversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Are you using the new high availability datastore? The docs don't specify but it's likely this experimental feature is not compatible with [the deprecated master/slave datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration).
- If your app is using Java, you have to [deploy a non-default Python app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Backup_And_Restore) to use the backup/restore feature (search for "a note for java developers" on the page).
- How large is your datastore? It may take awhile to enable the feature on very large datastores.
- How long is your app's name? The error you are seeing is DNS related. The Datastore Admin feature seems to make a request to:

  ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-latest-dot-[YOUR APP NAME].appspot.com

  at one point. Due to the length of that subdomain name, if your app name is longer than roughly 23 characters, you'll get a DNS error because DNS is limited to 63 characters per domain section:

  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax

  In my limited testing, I was able to get to a longer domain name by adding the ah-builtin-python-bundle... domain name directly to my system's etc/host file:

  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here it goes: 1) Yes it's high-availability. 2) It's a Java App, but the "note for Java developers" you refer to is only about the "copy" feature, not about backup/restore. 3) The Datastore is fairly small (it's a test instance, I only have a few different entities with a few records each in there).

Comment: App name is 24 characters - sounds like that might be it! I have another one < 24 chars that is not giving me the same error so this is promising. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did hosts file solve? Can you accept before bounty grace expires?

Comment: Accepted, I was verifying your hypothesis (seems to be the case) and also thought you'd get the points automatically as the top answer